# Preserve (local) ownerships and permissions with sshfs

Tags: ssh, permissions, mount, sshfs

If I mount a sshfs point as root and use the option `allow_other`, then on the original server (SERVERA) the files are owned by the SSH user, and on the destination server (SERVERB) they are accessible (writable) by everyone.

Is it possible instead to do the mount in a way that, on SERVERB, I can preserve ownership and permission metadata?

For example, let's say that on SERVERB I have users bob and tom, I create (as root) a folder, I chown it to bob and then bob can manage his own files as if they would be on a local disk (in particular he can prevent tom to read/write some files/folders).

I am interested in a new empty share, so preserving of old data to match users on the server is not important for me.